# "What has X got to do with Y" - how come this "wordy" construction survived thus far?

Tags: colloquialisms, construction

When someone is wondering how two things may be related to each other, they will probably say "**what has X got to do with Y?**". This utterance uses simple words, with no words specific to the idea of relation or connection. Of course, one might say "How are the two related?" or some other phrasing, but I think that the phrase in question is the most common, at least colloquially.

My question is **how could this construction survive the natural process of language simplification** (I do hope my meaning is clear, I wanted to add a reference, but I am not familiar with the professional terminology, so I was unable to find it online), since like I said it is rather "wordy" and "bulky" - especially when spoken, it takes a (relatively) long time to utter.

N.B. 
English is not my first language. In Hebrew, the same idea would be conveyed by the phrase: "מה הקשר?" (transliterated: *Ma Hakesher?*, literally: *What is the relation\connection?*). Although English and Hebrew are hardly related to one another, the stark difference in complexity of the phrase sparked this question.

Comment: Note that the English mentions both X snd Y.  the Hebrew seems to ask something closer to, “So what?”  “What’s your point?” “Yeah, And...?”

Comment: How would you say it more simply, while still identifying the two ideas for which correlation was being claimed?  Seems like any statement would require about as many words,

Comment: Could downvoters (or anyone of their opinion) please explain the reason for downvoting? This question concerns a commonly used phrase in English and strives to shed light on the relationship between structure and meaning. Is this truly the wrong place to post it?

Comment: It survives because it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

I remember in Scotland when arguing a problem that needed a solution, if someone began a wordy and prolix discussion of generalities, my colleague would bring it back to the point by saying "Aye, and what's that got to do with the price of fish."

It worked.

I'm not sure there is a "natural process of language simplification". When I was a (very bad) teacher, each new year had new words, new argots, to mark their identities. Language is a wild dance, not a logical system.

"What's X got to do with Y" is perhaps a phrase we know, respond to, rather than a mathematical construction. Tina Turner I think had a powerful song "What's love got to do, got to do with it; what's love but a second-hand emotion."

That worked too.

The phrase is not that bulky or wordy. "What's X got to do with Y" has no more syllables than "How are the two related". And it punches. It is a clash in debate, while the other is a matter of studious examination.